# Javascript setTimer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind the setTimer method in javascript.

```
 <html><head>
    <script>
        function Timer () {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();

    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
        t = setTimeout("Timer()", 1000); 
      }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="Timer()">
<div id="show"></div>
</body></html>
```

setTimeout is used to delay a function/method execution. Then why it is being used in a real-time clock?

```
t = setTimeout("Timer()", 1000);
```

This part is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `Timer()` function is called, it schedules itself to be run again one second later. The end result is once every second, `Timer()` updates the `show` element with the current time. (I have no idea why it's assigned to `t`, unless `t` is used in some other code on the page.)

Comment: so you mean the `<body onload="Timer()">` gets loaded again every 1 second?

Comment: @user1666411 - The `<body onload="Timer()">` causes `Timer()` to be called the first time, after the page has loaded. (The use of `onload` is to ensure that the 'show' element exists.) Each call to `Timer()` then schedules one more call that will occur one second later. None of these calls cause the page to be loaded again; they just update the one element with id 'show'.

Comment: The value that gets assigned to `t` is the timer id, that can be used in `clearTimeout` to stop the timer. In this case with the clock `setInterval` is a better choice: only one timer id is used and it won't drift. Can be stopped with `clearInterval`.

Comment: @some—saying `it won't drift` is not correct. Any timer using a fixed interval and either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` will drift, it will run slightly slower than the system clock. With setTimeout, the clock will skip a second from time to time, and may stop occasionally when the system is busy.

Comment: @some - I realize that the return value is an id. The point I was trying to make is that, if what OP posted is the complete web page, there's no reason to store the timer id in a variable that is not referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
t = setTimeout("Timer()", 1000);
```

The first thing you should know is that it's considered bad practice to put the first parameter in a string -- it should be the function name, unquoted, and without brackets, like so:

```
t = setTimeout(Timer, 1000);
```

That aside, your question about why it's being used to display a clock:

The use of `setTimeout()` inside the `Timer()` function to call itself is a common Javascript pattern to get a function to be called repeatedly. `setTimeout()` itself only triggers the function to be called a single time, after the given period of time has elapsed, so for a repeating event it needs to be re-triggered every time.

Since the `setTimeout` call is inside the `Timer()` function, it won't be set until `Timer()` is called the first time by some other means. This is where the `body onload` comes in.

As you suspect, `setTimeout()` isn't an accurate method for guaranteeing that a function will be called after exactly a given amount of time. Javascript is not multi-threaded, so any event handlers that are triggered must wait for any other code that is running at the same time. If something else is running slowly, this may cause your timer not to be triggered at exactly the moment it wants to be.

However, this isn't really a problem for your clock , because the clock is setting itself to the actual system time rather than relying on the `setTimeout` loop to keep itself in sync; the `setTimeout` loop is simply being used to make sure the display is updated (approximately) once a second. If it isn't actually quite exactly once a second, it doesn't really matter.

I hope that helps explain things a bit better.

Comment: I think you mean `setTimeout`, not `setTimer`. +1 anyway for pointing out the inaccuracy of the interval.

Comment: @RobG - hehe. yes. corrected it. thanks for spotting the error.

Answer (score 2):

The clock is recursively calling itself, after the elapsed period of time.

Making a real-time clock is impossible in JS.
Because of how JS engines work, if you put `Timer` in a loop, to run for an infinite period of time, you'd never see the time update on the screen (as changes aren't drawn to the window until a function finishes and there's a gap in the program).
Also, inside that infinite-loop, it would be impossible to do anything else with the page (even closing it), because JS can only do one thing at a time, so it can't listen to any of the user's clicking until it's done with this loop.......

So that's what the `setTimeout` is for.

`Timer` is the function which acts as the clock.
Inside of the `Timer` function, at the end when all of the work is done, it's telling `setTimeout` to wait 1 second (1000ms) and then to call a function called `Timer`.

`Timer` just so happens to be the same function.  But `setTimeout` doesn't know that, and doesn't care.

The `t` in this case is largely useless.  `setTimeout` will return a number -- like taking a number at the doctor's office.
If, before you go through with it, you decide to back out, you can call `clearTimeout(t);` and it'll skip over that call (in this case, it would stop calling the clock).

There are a few bad-practices in here, that I figure I should mention, so that you can try not to copy them in your own practice.

First:
Pass `setTimeout` a reference to a function, and not a string...

```
var runThisFunction = function () { console.log("It's the future!"); },
    time_to_wait = 250;

// DON'T DO THIS
setTimeout( "runThisFunction()", 250 );


 // DO THIS
 setTimeout( runThisFunction, 250 );
```

The difference is that `setTimeout` will run that string through `eval`, which can be a huge security concern depending on what you're trying to do.

The second problem is setting a random global variable, `t`...  ...and hoping to use that as a solution.
First, in a couple of years, JS engines are going to start yelling at people for doing that stuff.  Second, it's a huge hole, because any part of any app on that page could then overwrite `t`, or you could be relying on `t` somewhere else in your script, but every 1000ms, it gets written over with a new number.

Instead, they probably should have used a `Timer.start();` and `Timer.stop();` setup.

Comment: Don't forget `setInterval` (and `clearInterval`). You set the time ince (only uses ine timer id) and it runs "forever".

Comment: @some I wouldn't forget them.  But my problem with them is the same as my problem with `setTimeout`, here.  The person who wrote the example is "accidentally" intentionally setting a global variable, which they hope to use outside of the clock, which is just horrible practice.  Actually, `setInterval` might be worse in that case, because if anything after the first `Timer` writes over `t`, you can never stop the clock, without running `for...i<1000... clearInterval(i);` or something equally bad.  Also, the bad-practice of writing it in `<body onload="Timer()">` makes `setInterval` a bad idea.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. There is a lot of things that can be improved in the code. One of them is using `setInterval` once instead of multiple calls to `setTimeout`. If there is a need to stop the clock, the id should be saved inside the object, not globally. (I don't remember if the timer ids internally is 32 bit integers or 64 bit floats. The for-loop either has to go to 2147483647 or 9007199254740992. It is a very bad way to go.)

Comment: @some I get you.  And I agree that setInterval makes a lot more sense in the long-run.  But it wouldn't be the first thing I change (no `eval`, event-listener, object-based timer, enclosed `set/clearInterval` manipulated with `.start/.stop` methods) would probably be the order I look at, plus some element caching for "#show".  I consider setTimeout a bad choice.  I consider naive `eval` to be a security hole, and single-letter vars in global-scope a train-wreck in waiting.  Also, you're right about the numbers, but in my experience, not guaranteed, but likely to start much lower.

Comment: In my experience, implementations frequently start at 0 and increment. The loop isn't to be failproof.  Creating a for loop to clear an interval is a stupid proposition, but so is implicitly setting a global `t` in hopes that nobody in the world has written a script which is on the same page, which also sets a global `t`, and hinging the success of the page's code on that. Dumb solution to a dumb problem.  And I can tell you, as someone with first-hand experience with Adobe's enterprise-level analytics suite: having the global-scope clobbered by $50k/year software is a VERY REAL THING.

Comment: @Norguard—saying `eval, which can be a huge security concern` is completely off base. Eval is disliked primarily because it is an inefficient way to do things that should be done other ways, that's it.

Comment: @RobG - it is inefficient.  But to your point, from where I stand with new people who learn that it's great to eval random code generated from strings gained from wherever, what's stopping people from doing something like:  `var dirtyFunction = new Function("a", "b", ".../*completely unsanitized function definition as a remotely-received string*/);` If you have complete control over everything you are writing and doing, then there is never an issue... but again: a) it can happen more easily than elsewhere in code, b) even  enterprise-software gets this stuff wrong

Comment: I'm never worried about paranoid people doing ninja-things. I worry about people who know very, very little about a language or an environment, learning the absolute worst-case coding methodologies.  Sure, to start, it's pet-code, that's great. But we've still got document.write-based tutorials, DOM-0 events, DOM-reference caching problems in professional web-apps, non-existent APIs that introduce a dozen obfuscated (`s`, `s_f`,...) global variables with collision-likely names, in enterprise software from premium developers (at least in terms of digital-imaging, less-so in JS-writing).

Comment: So where, in all that, is the "huge security concern" with eval? There will always be people writing rubbish code, dramatising minor issues devalues, and detracts from, more relevant advice.

Comment: I suppose that's fair.  What about when that same person starts writing their first feed-display?  `setTimeout("writeInnerHTML(" + feed[i] + ")", 150)`.  Point being, if nobody ever points out those edge-cases, ever, then you'll never know they're there, until it's too late. Nobody told the Twitter guys that they should cache DOM references, instead of constantly `$(el)[method]()` on them, on am infinite timeline...  And that's Twitter.  Scaling good practices to a larger-scale invites fewer gotchas than scaling horrible practices.

Comment: @Norguard—popularity has never been an indicator of code quality. If Twitter is dependent on jQuery, whoever is responsible for the UI can't be too concerned about quality.

Comment: @RobG - the point I tried to make is that even the largest companies are full of people who ran with JavaScript libraries, before they even learned to walk through a closure. Or came in from Java, and didn't bother to figure out why it's better not to try to subclass, but try to stuff it in there, anyway.

Comment: For people who are trying to learn, at this point, the internet is still full of tutorials which are horrible for learning anything low-level, in terms of performance, security or even just basic architecture, when most of them start with "get this library, download these plugins and write these three lines of \"code\"", or "create all these global variables in pet-code", without anything deeper. Even discussing the validity of concerns is better than naught. There are some great books/resources out there, but finding them under the crap is hard enough...

Answer (score 0):

The line starts The function again after one second.